# wordpress seo friendly url doesn't recognise template

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I have a website where there are profiles. I have changed the `.htaccess` so it give me a nice URL back, for example.

SEO unfriendly URL:

`www.domain.com/index.php?page_id=216&acctype=trainer&stname=name`

of trainer (with - instead of spaces).

Now I managed to get it like the following:

`www.domain.com/profiel/trainer/name-of-trainer`

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^profiel/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?page_id=216&acctype=$1&stname=$2 [L]
```

All I get is that the page is not found.

I have a page in WordPress (profiel) and have a template linked to that page, could it be that the `acctype` (type of account), is making it that the template is not being found?

Hope that the explanation is clear, if not, please ask.

Hope some one can help.

I have setup the permalinks correctly, because the url is showing, it only doesn't show the correct template, it should show more detailed info about that specific user.
I am wondering what is going wrong, have no clue at this tried.

Comment: have you used permalinks url from admin section?

Comment: `profiel` != `profile`

Comment: @mario, it indeed profiel, but I have that correct, was a typo here

Answer (score 1):

The wordpress post and page urls are stored into database too.
When you change your url rewrite on .htaccess that changes base redirection only. You need to change permalink on `Settings > Permalink Settings > Select your url pattern` By using this the wordpress automatically change .htaccess and all post url and page url on **database** to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change in your `.htaccess` file to make the URL SEO friendly. Just login the admin panel

> Settings > Permalink Settings > Select Post Name from the given options

Using this way you can make URL SEO friendly in WordPress.